# Packaging a kivy app for OSX: 'no module named main'

Tags: macos, kivy, buildozer

Ive written a small kivy app, and am trying to package it for use on a Mac. I followed the first set of instructions here for using bulldozer:

https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-osx.html

Buildozer runs with no error messages, but when I try and run the application it produces nothing happens. When running it in the terminal I get the following output:

```
Williams-MBP:desktop w.gerrard$ /Users/w.gerrard/Desktop/RPtest.app/Contents/MacOS/Kivy 
2017-02-17 18:01:47.955 Kivy[35472:9517065] NSDocumentController Info.plist warning: The values of CFBundleTypeRole entries must be 'Editor', 'Viewer', 'None', or 'Shell'.
2017-02-17 18:01:47.966 Kivy[35472:9517065] Application did finish launching
2017-02-17 18:01:47.968 Kivy[35472:9517065] Running task
/bin/bash '/Users/w.gerrard/Desktop/RPtest.app/Contents/Resources/script'
2017-02-17 18:01:48.185 Kivy[35472:9517065] Appending output: "/Users/w.gerrard/Desktop/RPtest.app/Contents/Resources/python: No module named main"
/Users/w.gerrard/Desktop/RPtest.app/Contents/Resources/python: No module named main
2017-02-17 18:01:48.187 Kivy[35472:9517065] Task finished
2017-02-17 18:01:48.187 Kivy[35472:9517065] Output empty
Williams-MBP:desktop w.gerrard$
```

Im really just looking for any indication as to what I might be doing wrong. Other info which might be relevant:

Im using kivy v1.9.1-dev0 which uses python v2.7.10. The basic outline of my program is:

```
Kivy string '''
...
'''

Class Graph(App):
.
.
.

Some function definitions:
.
.
.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Graph().run()
```

I also tried the second set of instructions in the link which use the kivy SDK, but I keep getting the error: 'no module named docopt' even though docopt is present in the kivy package.

Comment: Is your file called main.py?

Comment: no, the only reference to the word main in the whole code is at the bottom of that code above, do you think that might fix it ?

Comment: that fixed it, can't believe it was that simple, thank you !